# Execute a TSQL command using variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

I have files that I need to bulk insert into SQL server:

```
@Date char(8) = '20200429' *--this is a specific file variable*
```

so the paths are as follows:

```
root path: @ROOT = 'G:\app\Data\table-dump\'
filepath: @FILEPATH = @date+'\'+@Date+'-230000-file.txt'
fullpath: @FULLPATH = @ROOT + @FILEPATH
```

I want to run a bulk insert into a table called **dbo.TableDump_IMPORT**

SO I constructed this:

```
DECLARE @BULKINSERT as varchar(max) 
SET @BULKINSERT= 'BULK INSERT dbo.TableDump_IMPORT FROM ' + @FULLPATH + ' WITH (    FIRSTROW = 2,   FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'',    ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0A'')'
EXEC @BULKINSERT
```

When I run the command I get this error:

```
The name 'BULK INSERT dbo.TableDump_IMPORT FROM G:\app\Data\table-dump\20200429\20200429-230000-file.txt WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2,   FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',  ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A')' is not a valid identifier.
```

How do I get it to just execute the BULK INSERT command?

Comment: `EXEC (@BULKINSERT)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the filepath in single quotes.

```
SET @BULKINSERT= 'BULK INSERT dbo.TableDump_IMPORT FROM ''' + @FULLPATH + ''' WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0A'')'
```

Comment: A combination of this and **EXEC (@BULKINSERT)** worked